# How to install everything without getting an error?

Tags: apt, 20.04, deepin-desktop-environment

Everytime I install an app I will get an error. Why? Because of the "deepin-anything-server". Here come what I get when trying to autoremove.

```
nguyen@X553MA:~$ LANG=C sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for nguyen: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  deepin-anything-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 469 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 404624 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing deepin-anything-server (5.0.1-4) ...
userdel: user 'deepin-anything-server' does not exist
Failed on delete user deepin-anything-server
dpkg: error processing package deepin-anything-server (--remove):
 installed deepin-anything-server package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 deepin-anything-server
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My Ubuntu 20.04 install have been **apt**-bricked. Tell me what should I do?

[NOTE Oct 7, 2021: I have closed this question thank to someone suggested another one whose **that was** the same as mine. Check the notif on top of my question. Thank you, all. Following the answer which have been [assoicated][Can't install and uninstall packages, can't also remove dde](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361323/cant-install-and-uninstall-packages-cant-also-remove-dde), that issue is fixed.]

Comment: Please run the commands prefixed with `LANG=C` like so: `LANG=C sudo apt autoremove`; it makes the system write in English, and many more people can understand.

Comment: `deepin` is not Ubuntu nor can `deepin`'s repositories be expected to work with Ubuntu. Remove the references to `deepin-server`.

Comment: @sudodus OK I will try.

Comment: @sudodus | Edits made.
N0rbert | Thank you for suggesting another question, that and currently ongoing. Please don't take action on the question.
waltinator | If deepin is not Ubuntu then how they can give a beautiful look that was 99% more beautiful than Windows and Mac!?

Comment: Thanks @pphu15 for making the output in English and for sharing your solution (in this case that another question has an answer that help you solve your problem :-)